# Validacion de Formulario en html con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, formularios

'Buenas soy nuevo en esto, estoy haciendo una validación de un formulario pero necesito una vez comprobado que estén puestos todos los input correctamente que al final salga un mensaje diciendo que se envió correctamente. Quiero hacer la verificación y el mensaje de confirmación en javascript. Pongo el codigo de script solamente porque es muy extenso el html.
Funciona bien la validación de los elementos del formulario pero me falta enviar un mensaje después de la validación

```
             ' <script>         
              (function(){
                var formulario = document.getElementsByName('formulario')[0],
                    elementos = formulario.elements,
                boton= document.getElementById('btn');

                var validarNombre = function(e){
                    if(formulario.nombre.value ==0){
                        alert("Completa el nombre");
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
                var validarDepartamento = function(e){
                    if(formulario.departamento.value ==0){
                        alert("Completa departamento");
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
                var validarOficina = function(e){
                    if(formulario.oficina.value ==0){
                        alert("Completa la oficina");
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                    
                }
                var validarEmail = function(e){
                    if(formulario.email.value ==0){
                        alert("Completa el email");
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
                var validarCheckbox = function (e){
                    if (formulario.equipo.checked == true || formulario.email2.checked == true || formulario.redes.checked == true || formulario.telefono.checked == true || formulario.otro.checked == true){}
                    else{
                    alert("Completa al menos una opcion del tipo del problema");
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                
                };
                var validarProblema = function(e){
                    if(formulario.problema.value ==0){
                        alert("Completa la especificacion");
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
                
                var validar = function(e){
                    validarNombre(e);
                    validarDepartamento(e);
                    validarOficina(e);
                    validarEmail(e);
                    validarCheckbox(e);
                    validarProblema(e);                 
                }
                
                formulario.addEventListener("submit", validar);     
                
                }())
        
      
      </script>'
```

Comment: ok y que no te funciona? La validación, no sale el mensaje??

Comment: Por cada input valida bien y sale las alertas, mi problema es como coloco una alerta si todo esta bien, es decir, una vez corroborado todos los input que salga un mensaje diciendo que el formulario se envio correctamente

Comment: En la función validar al final de todo pon tu alerta, también podrías poner cada función en un if para saber si se cumple o no y si llega al final muestras la alerta

Answer (score 0):

Podrías darle valor a las variables que estás creando y al final verficar que sean true, te doy un ejemplo con tu método para validar nombre:

```
var validarNombre = function(e){
  if(formulario.nombre.value ==0){
    alert("Completa el nombre");
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
  else{
  return true;
  }
}
```

Lo único que agregué fueron los 2 return, esto lo que hará será indicarnos si la función devolvió un valor positivo o negativo, si es valido o no es valido. Entonces lo siguiente que queda hacer es verificarlo en tu funcion de validar, te dejo un pequeño ejemplo:

```
var validar = function(e){
  var validacion = true;
  if(validarNombre(e) == false){
    validacion = false;
  }
}
```

Como puedes ver, la variable "validacion" tiene un valor por defecto true, si este valor llega a cambiar en algún momento, significa que algo salió mal ya que la única forma de que cambie es que el if de validarNombre o demás retorne false, de esta manera puedes saber cuándo es que una validación no fue correcta. Ahora sí, como último paso solo verifica que la variable "validacion" no tenga false, en caso de que sí, lanza tu alerta:

```
if(validacion == false){
    alert("Validación incorrecta, intente de nuevo.");
}
else{
    alert("Validación correcta!");
}
```

Espero haber ayudado, suerte!

Comment: Hola @Jasso me gusto tu solucion, pero cuando la ejecuto me tira error de que no esta definido validacion.

Comment: lo solucione asi    'var validar = function(e){

  if(validarNombre(e) == false){
    alert("se envio correctamente");
  }
}'

Comment: Perfecto! Me alegra que lo hayas podido solucionar :)